# Creating a Workflow Variable that works out what day of the week it is?

Tags: workflow

[image]I am creating a workflow for a HelpDesk list that will send a Manager a notification if a task has been outstanding for 2 days. I have successfully created the HelpDesk List/Workflow I just want the workflow to check to see a specific date and not send the Manager an email during the weekend. Is there any way around this? [image: Below is a screenshot of my workflow so far]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Saturday / Sunday in your pause date and add 1 or 2 days to the pause date. So the workflow can wait 2 or 3 or 4 days based on your logic.

The workflow can be modified as follows.
[image]

EDIT: Add a plain text to the workflow variable
[image]

EDIT: Set long date to a workflow variable
[image]

Comment: Can I ask, where the Saturday & Sunday fields will come from? Or do I need to create them myself?

Comment: They are simple text, not fields. I will add screenshot if need further

Comment: You just type text in the right side portion of the condition.

Comment: If you could add a screenshot that would be brilliant. When I attempt to add Saturday/Sunday as simple text it will not allow me to.

Comment: In my screenshot you see there is `...`. You can click that to open a window to type your text

Comment: It still won't allow me type my own Value, when I click on the ellipsis it only allows me to select current date or Specific date.

Comment: I got it. In my above case "longDate" is a string type variable. I have edited answer how to set long date to string variable

Comment: Venkat...... It looks as if I am now on the right track, thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @Venkat, I have managed to create the workflow but this is the error I get when the workflow is running... Any ideas?

Comment: May I know the what error you are getting?

Comment: I can't paste the entire error into the comments box but in the first piece of the error says "RequestorId: 2fae055e-5453-19eb-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: The value 'd/results(0)/Created_x0020__x0028_Date_x0020_' cannot be read as type 'DateTime'. at"

Comment: Are you using any action "HTTP Web Call" in your workflow?

Comment: I have not used the HTTP Web Call within my workflow, just the usual Conditions and Actions.

Comment: I need to see your flow where this "Create Date" field being used there it throw error

Comment: Have added a screenshot of my flow above

Comment: You need to add a screenshot to your question, not for my answer.

Comment: Sorry Venkat. Have now added the screenshot to my question.

Comment: I am suspecting you are getting the error in the second log statement. Do you see first log statement in the workflow history?

Comment: Sorted the error out earlier on, cheers Venkat!